# What was the first game to have a "quicksave" feature?

Tags: gaming-history

Quicksave (according to Wikipedia, and my own experience) is a feature that allows the player to save their game state with a single keystroke, instead of (say) going through a lot of complicated menus. The "FPS" shooter *Wolfenstein 3D* (1992) had this feature.

(I grew up with old 8-bit machines, where you could buy add-on  hardware like disk interfaces that might have a special "snapshot button" -- but that doesn't count. It wasn't built into the game.)

Were there earlier games with a quicksave feature? What was the first game to have this feature?

Comment: This isn't really meaningful -- the earliest games to support saving state generally did so using a single button press.  Menu-driven saving (and menus in general) came later.